# How to create an installer for WPF in VS 2012

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, installation, wpf-4.0

As I am looking in project types the good old setup project is gone. Is there any way I can create a setup installer for my project?

I had a look at wix toolset and it's got quiet a learning curve with XML etc for a simple task of creating setup.

Is there something easy than wix which can save my time and offers GUI rather than me having to type all that silly stuff?

Comment: Have you tried [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/t71a733d(v=vs.80).aspx)? Some applications (e.g. Curse Client) are using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [InstallShield Limited Edition](http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio).
It offers a nice GUI